# Modal text disappear when datatable select in effect

Tags: datatables, modal-dialog

Hi I have a datatables with `select: true,`. In my table, there are three buttons, 2 buttons that only pass id and show `input file`. The other button is a dynamic button with ajax event being populated by another page.

The issue is that when I try to access the 2 earlier modal, the text is white if row is selected but if I click the modal or unselect the row, the text appears from the modal.

**Selected Row**
[image]

**Not selected row**
[image]

Based on my investigation, the `select` from the datatables is causing the issue. Is there a way to keep the select while also preventing such?

Thank you

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide a [mre] - something we can copy, paste and run for ourselves to recreate the issue.